# How to send a structure variable from client to socket?

Tags: c, sockets, client

I'm working on socket programming. The client has to send a structure variable to the server. How can I go about it? I have created the server and the client and I'm stuck at this point.

PS: I'm coding in C.

Answer (score 0):

Use write on the client side and read on the server side?
I think you have to be more precise..
Is it always the same data structure? if not how do you know which message you receive?

Comment: Yes, it is always the same data structure. I'll try implementing with write and read functions! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to send an instance of a struct, you could just send the binary data up (write the struct with the size of the struct). This assumes that you don't have any pointers in the struct, and that your struct definition matches perfectly on both sides (same bit alignment as well).

This is not very portable, and makes quite a few assumptions.

The better option is to encode the data into a standard format. I like JSON, mostly because it's simple and there are tons of parsers for it. You would encode the struct as JSON (see http://json.org/ for libraries), send it over the socket, and decode it on the other side.

You'd need to also send how big the data is, so you may need to come up with a simple protocol (first 4 bytes are the size of the JSON data, then send the JSON data).

Custom protocols are pretty terrible, so you may want to look into a standardized protocol. If you just want to send binary data over TCP, consider the WebSocket protocol. It's basically what I described, but a little more flexible.

This is what I do, and it works pretty well.